# Why? ROBOCOPY: ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Accessing Destination Directory. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: robocopy

Thanks in advance for your help.

I am using `ROBOCOPY` to copy some files from on drive to another on the same computer. Every once in awhile, I get an error. And instead of retrying 999 times as it should, it retries once and fails. I have a couple questions:

1. Why would this error be happening in the first place?
2. Why isn't `ROBOCOPY` retrying the 999 times as defined?

Commands are below:

```
mkdir C:\Users\tempuser\AppData\Local\temp\test1
robocopy /R:999 /W:5 /NP /E /XO /NFL /NDL E:\test1 C:\Users\tempuser\AppData\Local\temp\test1 test*
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Monday, March 25, 2013 4:20:51 AM
   Source : E:\test1 
     Dest  : C:\Users\tempuser\AppData\Local\temp\test1

    Files : test*

  Options : /NDL /NFL /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /NP /XO /R:999 /W:5 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2013/03/25 04:20:51 ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Accessing Destination Directory C:\Users\tempuser\AppData\Local\temp\test1
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Waiting 5 seconds... Retrying...

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         0         0         1         0
   Files :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:05   0:00:00                       0:00:05   0:00:00
   Ended : Monday, March 25, 2013 4:20:56 AM
```

Answer (score 2):

This is quite probably a bug in robocopy. It has at least one other bug surrounding Error 32 / in use files: /b (backup) mode will fail with this error even if a file is not exclusively locked (and is copyable with 'copy', 'xcopy', windows explorer, and robocopy without /b), so I suspect there are bugs in how it handles in-use files in general.

Comment: That is NOT an answer. That's a comment. Where is the proof that ROBOCOPY has bugs? I suggest using handle.exe or some process ID tool to test if the destination dir is being used by ANOTHER actual process ID and I reckon it's the SQL Server Agent.

Comment: Well I'm struggling with the same. Process Explorer shows NO usage of the file. While Robocopy insists that it's in use. :(

Answer (score 1):

I hope someone finds this helpful. This "fix" has worked for me several times so good luck.

Simply logout of the server with file explorer and PowerShell running... force close any apps running at the sign-out Windows page and log back into the server . Run your robocopy script and your locked process would have been released.

Sorry if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: So far this seems to be working for me. I started a copy and quickly had about a dozen files get blocked because they were in use even though they are files that don't ever get touched. I turned off my real-time antivirus checks, assuming that was causing the contention. I still had more files getting blocked. I logged off and back in and it copied all those files it missed an so far has not been blocked on any others.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "bug" in ROBOCOPY.

Something is "locking" your source folders and files from time-to-time. Not always, as that's proof based on the fact that your copies work "at times".

I would place a script to copy "out" your source files into another location (drive preferably), and then use ROBOCOPY from that new location into your other or final location. Use the move option to keep the intermediate location free for the next backups, etc.

I use this...

```
robocopy <source path> <target path> <files> /s /j /r:2 /w:5 /log+:robocopy.log
```

Comment: Note that the OP's error message is about a _directory_ being unaccessible due to being used by another process; with a given _file_ that is in use the analogous error message (`Copying File ... The process cannot ...`) makes sense, but under what circumstances does robocopy consider a _directory_ exclusively locked?

Comment: @mklement0 no. It does not lock directories,

Comment: That's probably because there's no such thing as locking directories. The question I was asking, however, was why Robocopy _thinks_ the directory is locked, as suggested by the error message.